# Can not define a test case for selenium to find fox sports on google

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I need it to go to Google, type Fox Sports, and select Fox Sports website.
I recorded my action and created following, but it stuck on third step that is to click on the result link of Google.

Steps are as following

**1**

```
   Command       open
   Target    /
```

**2**

```
   Command     type
   Target     id=lst-ib 
   Value      Fox Sports
```

**3**

```
Command clickAndWait
Target link=FOX Sports: Home -- Sports News, Scores, Schedules ...
```

I have chosen all the suggested Targets but still does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I just tried and it worked. Not the waitForElementPresent that waits for the search result header. You could also wait for foxsports.com link to show.

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>open</td>
>   <td>/</td>
>   <td></td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>type</td>
>   <td>id=lst-ib</td>
>   <td>Fox Sports</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
>   <td>//h2[text()=&quot;Search Results&quot;]</td>
>   <td></td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>clickAndWait</td>
>   <td>//a[contains(text(),&quot;FOX Sports: Home&quot;)]</td>
>   <td></td>
> </tr>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I accepted Jsmith2800's answer as he posted his much earlier than you.

Comment: sure but his answer advises using a pause. Pauses should be avoided when possible because they can cause unnecessary delays in your tests. Think of it this way, would you rather pause 10 seconds EVERY test or only pause 2 seconds some times and 7 seconds other times? I advise WaitFors in place of pauses whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is putting a pause in between steps 2 and 3, it could be that it's trying to execute the clickAndWait before the link has actually loaded

Comment: Use WaitFor- commands instead of pauses where possible to help increase speed and efficiency of your tests.